# Azure Maps with OSM / WMS / other layers in OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, azure, openlayers, openstreetmap

I am trying to add an azure maps layer to my openlayers project. I can make a basic map work using  [this third party plugin and example](https://azuremapscodesamples.azurewebsites.net/Third%20Party%20Map%20Controls/Render%20Azure%20Maps%20in%20OpenLayers.html) with my azure maps key. However when I try to add an additional layer such as OSM or a WMS layer from Geoserver it throws an error in the console: "Uncaught TypeError: ol.source.OSM is not a constructor". I have many different layer types (OSM, WMS, XYZ) that I would like to add alongisde the Azure but I cannot get any of these to work, they are all throwing similar error.

Any ideas how to add other layers alongside Azure maps in Openlayers?

Relevant code snippet:

```
    <!-- Add reference to the Azure Maps OpenLayers plugin.-->
<script src="./js/azure-maps-openlayers.js"></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    var map;
    function GetMap() {

        //Add authentication details for connecting to Azure Maps.
        var authOptions = {
            authType: 'subscriptionKey',
            subscriptionKey: 'aaaaaaaabbbbbbbbccccccccddddddddd'
        };

        //Create a map instance.
        map = new ol.Map({
            target: 'myMap',
            layers: [
                new ol.layer.Tile({
                    type: 'base',
                    visible: true,  
                    source: new ol.source.AzureMaps({
                        authOptions: authOptions,
                        tilesetId: 'microsoft.imagery'
                    })
                }),
                new ol.layer.Tile({
                    type: 'overlay',
                    visible: false, 
                    source: new ol.source.OSM()
                })
            ],
            view: new ol.View({
                center: [0, 0],
                zoom: 2
            })
        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've managed to get this to work via the following code. It's actually posted on the Azure Maps Openlayers plugin page right at the bottom - "Alternative Option for OpenLayers". Ironically the plugin is not needed at all in order to get it to work - you just reference the Azure Maps layer as an ol.source.XYZ layer. Obviously you can change the visibility options of both layers in order to visualise them - or add them into a layer switcher.

```
        var map;
    function GetMap() {

        var subscriptionKey = 'my_subscription_key_goes_here';
        var tilesetId = 'microsoft.imagery';
        var language = 'EN';
        var view = new ol.View({
                center: [0, 0],
                zoom: 2
            });

        //Create a map instance.
        map = new ol.Map({
            target: 'myMap',
            layers: [
                new ol.layer.Tile({
                    type: 'base',
                    visible: true,                  
                    source: new ol.source.XYZ({
                        url: `https://atlas.microsoft.com/map/tile?subscription-key=${subscriptionKey}&api-version=2.0&tilesetId=${tilesetId}&zoom={z}&x={x}&y={y}&tileSize=256&language=${language}`,
                        attributions: `© ${new Date().getFullYear()} TomTom, Microsoft`
                    })
                }),
                new ol.layer.Tile({
                    type: 'overlay',
                    visible: true,  
                    source: new ol.source.OSM()
                })
            ],
            view: view
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done some research but I didn't found any scenario or document which suggests how can we integrate OSM layer with the Azure Maps in OpenLayers.

If you check this [Azure Maps Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/azure-maps-openlayers/azure-maps-openlayers-plugin/#:%7E:text=Extends:%20ol.source,AzureMaps%28options?:%20AzureMapsTileSourceOptions%29), you will understand why are you getting the error.

> **Namespace:**  `ol.source`
>
> A tile source that connects to the Azure Maps Render V2 services.
>
> **Contstructor**
> `AzureMaps(options?: AzureMapsTileSourceOptions)`

But if you want to integrate WSM layer with Azure Maps then you can achieve it by adding the OGC web-mapping service with Azure Maps as shown in the following code snippet.

```js
//Initialize a map instance.
var map = new atlas.Map('map', {
  view: "Auto",
  //Add your Azure Maps subscription client ID to the map SDK. Get an Azure Maps client ID at https://azure.com/maps
  authOptions: {
    authType: "anonymous",
    clientId: "04ec075f-3827-4aed-9975-d56301a2d663", //Your AAD client id for accessing your Azure Maps account

    getToken: function (resolve, reject, map) {
      //URL to your authentication service that retrieves an Azure Active Directory Token.
      var tokenServiceUrl = "https://azuremapscodesamples.azurewebsites.net/Common/TokenService.ashx";

      fetch(tokenServiceUrl).then(r => r.text()).then(token => resolve(token));
    }
  }
});

//Wait until the map resources are ready.
map.events.add('ready', function () {

  map.layers.add(new atlas.layer.TileLayer({
    tileUrl: 'https://mrdata.usgs.gov/services/gscworld?FORMAT=image/png&HEIGHT=1024&LAYERS=geology&REQUEST=GetMap&STYLES=default&TILED=true&TRANSPARENT=true&WIDTH=1024&VERSION=1.3.0&SERVICE=WMS&CRS=EPSG:3857&BBOX={bbox-epsg-3857}',
    tileSize: 1024
  }), 'transit');
});
```

For more information check this [Add a tile layer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/map-add-tile-layer#add-a-tile-layer) Microsoft document.

If you want to work on Azure Maps with OpenLayers, then I would suggest you to Azure Maps OpenLayers plugin. OpenLayers  plugin makes it easy to overlay tile layers from the [Azure Maps tile services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/maps/render-v2/get-map-tile#tilesetid). You can only use the Azure Maps tile layers as shown in the example below.

```js
//Create a map instance.
 map = new ol.Map({ 
     target: 'myMap', 
     layers: [
          new ol.layer.Tile({ 
              source: new ol.source.AzureMaps({ 
                  authOptions: authOptions, 
                  tilesetId: 'microsoft.imagery' 
              }) 
        }),
        new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.AzureMaps({
                authOptions: authOptions,
                tilesetId: 'microsoft.base.road'
            })
        }) 
    ], 
    view: new ol.View({ 
        center: [0, 0], 
        zoom: 2 
    }) 
});
```

I would strongly suggest to read this [Azure Maps OpenLayers plugin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/azure-maps-openlayers/azure-maps-openlayers-plugin/) document completely and also check this Azure-Samples/**[AzureMapsCodeSamples](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/AzureMapsCodeSamples)** GitHub code sample for more information.